# lxpanel Application Menu Lost Icons

Tags: 14.04, icons, appmenu, lxpanel

My lxpanel, when I first installed it on Ubuntu 14.04, came with application menu icons. However, now suddenly they are gone. How do I get them back?

Comment: Have you tried `lxpanelctl restart`?

Comment: Yes, as well as a system restart.

Comment: Maybe if I could learn what file makes this menu, it would help. I could see if the file is missing a parameter, for instance.

Comment: Didn't help in my case. I found the panels folder and I see the settings there, but they look default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to run this command as any user where you need this, including root if for instance you do `gksudo` to run something under root for a certain requirement you might have.

```
gtk-theme-switch2
```

I opened this and then applied the Adwaita theme. Instantly, lxpanel showed the icons I needed.

If you don't have this command, check to see if you can add it with `apt-get update; apt-get install gtk-theme-switch2`. This edits the `.gtkrc` file, which is an old GTK2 holdover, and since lxpanel is written in GTK2 instead of GTK3, it pulls from this. Previously I had this styled with the `lxappearance` command, but then that screws up the lxpanel's icons for some strange reason.